# Problems linking GLFW with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, static-linking, glfw

I'm trying to add GLFW to my C++ project in CLion. I've downloaded the pre-built Windows binaries, and I'm attempting to add them to my CMake file, but I'm getting errors. Here's my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12.3)
project(Streamlined)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "$(CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")

add_executable(Streamlined src/main.cpp)

find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${GLFW_LIBRARY})
```

And my cmake/Findglfw3.cmake file:

```
set(FIND_GLFW_PATHS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../Library/glfw-3.2.1.bin.WIN64/lib)

find_path(GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR glfw3.h
        PATH_SUFFIXES include
        PATHS ${FIND_GLFW_PATHS})

find_library(GLFW_LIBRARY NAMES libglfw3
        PATH_SUFFIXES lib
        PATHS ${FIND_GLFW_PATHS})
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findglfw3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3" with any of
  the following names:

    glfw3Config.cmake
    glfw3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "glfw3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "glfw3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "glfw3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I created the Findglfw3.cmake file, and appended it to CMAKE_MODULE_PATH, so I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I attempted [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369168/linking-glfw-on-clion-cmake) as well, but I'm getting a "PkgConfig not found" error.

Comment: Are you sure CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR is correct?

Comment: You have a typo when refers to `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` variable: instead of open **braces** `'(` it should be open **curly braces** `{`. Also, when refer current directory from a `CMakeLists.txt`, it is better to use `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` variable. Variable `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` is mainly for scripts, which are included via `include` or `find_package`.